# Header Issue when i send web url to others(always appear Odoo text )

Tags: python, odoo

1 . abstract_web_client.js

```
init: function (parent) {
        this.client_options = {};
        mixins.ServiceProvider.init.call(this);
        this._super(parent);
        this.origin = undefined;
        this._current_state = null;
        this.menu_dm = new concurrency.DropMisordered();
        this.action_mutex = new concurrency.Mutex();
        this.set('title_part', {"zopenerp": "Lts"});
    },
```

2 . webclient_template.xml

```
<template id="web.layout" name="Web layout">&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
        <html t-att="html_data or {}">
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8"/>
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>

                <title t-esc="title or 'Lts'"/>
                <link type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon" t-att-href="x_icon or '/web/static/src/img/favicon.ico'"/>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var odoo = {
                        csrf_token: "<t t-esc="request.csrf_token(None)"/>",
                    };
                </script>

                <t t-raw="head or ''"/>
            </head>
            <body t-att-class="body_classname">
                <t t-raw="0"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </template>
```

When i send site url to others skype or linkedin there is a problem that the Odoo string appeared in header .i will change the title .but never chnage the text. but icon is changed.i am using python(3) odoo 11.can you please tell me the solution.

Comment: You need to do de branding in odoo.

Comment: sir i am already installed that odoo debranding module.@keval mehta